# Summation of: $\sum_{1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^x$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, statistics, summation

This is a subsection in my statistics homework. It goes back to calculus II and summations, and it's been a long time since I've studied it so I'm rusty.

I'm looking to solve the summation of $c\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^x$ where $c$ is a constant to where I can solve for $c$.

I understand that we say that this summation is:
$$c\left[\frac{2}{3}+\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2 +\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^3 +\cdots\right]$$
But the book then says that this then equals to:

$$c\dfrac{\dfrac{2}{3}}{1-\dfrac{2}{3}}$$

Any help?

Also I know my coding ability is little to none so if you'd like to edit my question to make it look more presentable feel free to.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

This is a geometric series, and it converges since $2/3 <1$.

If we write $$S=c ( (2/3) + (2/3)^2 + (2/3)^3 + \cdots )$$ then we see that $$(2/3) S = c ( (2/3)^2 + (2/3)^3 + (2/3)^4 + \cdots )$$

subtracting $(2/3)S$ from $S$ we find: $$( 1-(2/3) )S = c ( 2/3)$$ Now if we solve for $S$ we have: $$S = \frac{c(2/3)}{1-(2/3)}$$ which is the answer provided in your homework.

Comment: is there any set rule you can give me for future problems like this? I've tried to google around but I didn't find any that gave an answer of r/1-r such as my homework says the answer is

Comment: @ColeHowie I promise you it is there in the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum).

Comment: @ColeHowie : You might Google the term "geometric series".  A geometric series is a series with a common ratio, i.e. the number you multiply a term by to get the next term is the same in all cases. ${}\qquad{}$